# why do WEKA NaiveBayes classifier gives a std. dev. value for all-zero attribute?

Tags: r, weka, r-caret, standard-deviation, naivebayes

```
@relation weather
@attribute outlook {'overcast','rainy','sunny'}
@attribute temperature numeric
@attribute humidity numeric
@attribute windy {'FALSE','TRUE'}
@attribute play {'no','yes'}
@attribute attr numeric
@data
'sunny',85,85,'FALSE','no',4
'sunny',80,90,'TRUE','no',9
'overcast',83,86,'FALSE','yes',0
'rainy',70,96,'FALSE','yes',0
'rainy',68,80,'FALSE','yes',0
'rainy',65,70,'TRUE','no',4
'overcast',64,65,'TRUE','yes',0
'sunny',72,95,'FALSE','no',3
'sunny',69,70,'FALSE','yes',0
'rainy',75,80,'FALSE','yes',0
'sunny',75,70,'TRUE','yes',0
'overcast',72,90,'TRUE','yes',0
'overcast',81,75,'FALSE','yes',0
'rainy',71,91,'TRUE','no',8
```

Above is the weather.arff data from WEKA, and I just manually added one artificial attribute "attr" to it. "play {'no', 'yes'} is the class. Notice that all the "attr" values for "yes" class samples are 0.

When I use WEKA NaiveByes classifier to build a model ("Use training set"), the output model looks like this:

```
=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Naive Bayes Classifier

                 Class
Attribute           no     yes
                (0.38)  (0.63)
===============================
outlook
  overcast          1.0     5.0
  rainy             3.0     4.0
  sunny             4.0     3.0
  [total]           8.0    12.0

temperature
  mean          74.8364 72.9697
  std. dev.       7.384  5.2304
  weight sum          5       9
  precision      1.9091  1.9091

humidity
  mean          86.1111 78.8395
  std. dev.      9.2424  9.8023
  weight sum          5       9
  precision      3.4444  3.4444

windy
  FALSE             3.0     7.0
  TRUE              4.0     4.0
  [total]           7.0    11.0

attr
  mean             5.85       0
  std. dev.         2.7   0.375
  weight sum          5       9
  precision        2.25    2.25
```

For the "attr" attribute in class "yes", there's a mean of 0 but a sd of 0.375. I was wondering how NaiveBayes in WEKA calculate this. Does it use some correction method?

Also, when I tried to do this in R with caret package:

```
library(caret)
library(foreign)
weather <- read.arff('weather.arff')
set.seed(1)
fit <- train(play ~., data = weather, method = 'nb', trControl = trainControl(method = 'none'), tuneGrid = data.frame(fL = 0, usekernel = F))
```

Error pops out saying:

```
Error in NaiveBayes.default(x, y, usekernel = param$usekernel, fL = param$fL,  : 
  Zero variances for at least one class in variables: attr
Called from: NaiveBayes.default(x, y, usekernel = param$usekernel, fL = param$fL, 
    ...)
```

How can I tell R to ignore this all-zero attribute situation and give me a (corrected) model?

Comment: I have the same question; need someone's help!

Answer (score 1):

for the attr column the precision is equal to 2.75

in class: weka.estimators.NormalEstimator, we have:

89     // Allow at most 3 sd's within one interval
90     m_StandardDev = m_Precision / (2 * 3);

so the minimum standar deviation for the attribute attr is 0.375

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).